# how to keep state data after refresh the page in nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

Nuxt3 State data loss when refresh the page.

I also use localStorage and sessionStorage but the data is loss.

How can i keep state data after refresh the page.

This is my source code.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHSl5.png)

Comment: do you load the data from localStorage/sessionStorage when the page loads?

Comment: yes , is it false?
I don't know very well using of localstorage.

Comment: we need to see your code. Can you post your code please.

Comment: In the case of localStorage, there is no possibility of losing data until it is intentionally deleted. plz check you code you might calling any method to remove localstorage data in components lifecycle hook. because I use it alot of time and that's working fine

Comment: In the whole project , i used localstorage one time and there is no code to remove or delete localstorage data in lifecycle.

Comment: Edit your question and post your code in your question please. It isn't easy to read if you post it as a comment. Also, please post the whole code of your component.

Comment: I added source code with pic

Comment: We need to know the values in the testState variable please... Try to think about giving us all the information we need to help you.

Comment: I understanded when i checked testState variable.

I use initialData as the value of useState.

That's why my localStorage is updated as a blank.

I want to apologize  for my careless.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to explain the localStorage. I can't help you more without the entire code. That said, try getting the data from the localStorage before setting it. I'm guessing `testState.value.input.val` is empty, when you refresh. You're then saving `empty` to the localStorage and then retrieve it.

try `localStorage.getItem` before `localStorage.setItem`

Explanation:
The State allows you to share a data across components/pages. It will initilize when you start/refresh your app. The localStorage data stays saved in your browser. I would recommend to use `localStorage.setItem()` alongside with `useTestState().setState()` Meaning there where you save the data to the State also save it to the localStorage. Then where you initialize the State initialize it with `localStorage.getItem()`